# Is it possible to make a dynamic font-size based on the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element which has an specific dimensions *(I mean, constant width and height)*. I want to change the font size of the text in it to avoid something comes out of the container.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test.
</div>


<div>
whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test.
</div>
```

In this ^ fiddle, the font size of the first `<div>` should be bigger to fill the container, and in the second one, the font size should be less because nothing should come out of the container.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Someone wrote a script in Coffeescript and jQuery at https://coderwall.com/p/_8jxgw/autoresize-text-to-fit-into-a-div-width-height

Comment: this may help http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a default `font-size`, if the content is overflowing with this font size then the following snippet will reduce the font-size

```js
// checking if with current font size if the text is overflowing
function isOverflown(element) {
  return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight || element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
}

// get all div and itrate over the array
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(item) {
  // get the font size and 
  let fontSize = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(item, null).getPropertyValue("font-size"), 10);
  // for the font size check if the current content is overflowing the container
  for (let i = fontSize; i >= 0; i--) {
    let overflow = isOverflown(item);
    // if overflowing then reduce the font size
    if (overflow) {
      fontSize--;
      // add the font size property to the container
      item.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test.
</div>


<div>
  whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test.whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this
  is. this is a test.whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test.whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a test. whatever this is. this is a
  test. whatever this is. this is a test.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to show the overflow text in particular element. But it is not good idea to reduce the font size, if font size is already very small. You can add **overflow: auto** css to element. You can try **overlow: overflow/ overflow-x/overflow-y** properties.

Even if you want to reduce the size of font, you need to take the help of **javaScript/jQuery** to count the characters and add the font size to element as you required.

**jQuery:**

```
var chrLen = $("#div").text().length;
if(chrLen > 70) {
    $("#div").css("fontSize","10px");
    // OR
    $("#div").addClass("className");
}
```

**javaScript:**

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var txt = div.innerHTML;
var chrLen = txt.length;
if(chrLen > 70) {        
    div.style.fontSize = "10px";
    // OR
    div.classList = "className"
}
```